# Meteor as a native OSX or Windows 8 app

Tags: windows, node.js, macos, meteor, native

Is there any way to take my meteor app and turn it into a native desktop app on OSX or Windows 8? Something that I can put in the App Store or put a download link to as a DMG on my website?

I'm looking for something fairly simple to use. Sort of like a Phonegap for the desktop except with meteor and node.js support.

Comment: I'm not sure about the meteor support, but have a look at https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

Comment: I have a similar question with a few more specifics over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898467/how-can-i-start-a-meteor-instance-before-launching-a-node-webkit

Comment: This would be a great feature. So far the only way I know to build a native OSX app using front-end is Tide SDK. It's not exactly what you're looking for but it might be helpful: http://www.tidesdk.org

Comment: Are you wanting to install the entire application (including MongoDB, etc)?  Or do you just want a thin web-client shim to your web server?

Answer (score 1):

There is a project under works for that. It's still in early stages, but you should be able to build an app with it. It's a way to interface with your app's Meteor server via DDP and connect that data in a native iOS app.

Here is the project: https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

MacGap2 allows you to do that. It basically just allows you to run HTML/JS/CSS based apps as a native OSX app.

Check http://docs.macgap.com/